# How to trigger OnTouchListener programmatically

Tags: android

I have an `OnTouchListener` that I would like to simulate programmatically. For example, I want to hit a button and have the `OnTouchListener` registered and move to the left 200px. I want this for debugging purposes.

Comment: Debugging or for automated unit tests?

Comment: This is for debugging.

Comment: Why not using Android device manager and create a virtual machine to debug that code in an easier way?

Comment: I use a gesture that pans and scales two images at the same time. My problem is that, although the scaling works correctly, the scaled images do not keep their relative positions to each other. I want to be able to scale and pan a set amount so that I can analyse what sort of math needs to be done to get them moving correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `View#performClick()` to click on view. 
Also you can send TouchEvent to root view manually.

Create your motion event:

```
MotionEvent myEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(long downTime, long eventTime, int action, float x, float y, int metaState);
```

Send event:

```
Activity.this.dispatchTouchEvent(myEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you. I know what to research now.